# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 design time renders differently than runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, designer

I have a fairly simple wpf Window in the format of:

```
<Window>
    <Canvas>
        <Grid>
            <ListBox />
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

At design time everything looks the way I want it. There is no automatic resizing on any of the window controls.
However at runtime the Window has extra white space at the bottom and right side.

If I open the solution in Visual 2013 I can see this extra white space in the designer.

Has anyone ever come across this? I cant find anything online or any fixes released by Microsoft.

If I change the window size so that its borders are smaller than the controls in it then it looks fine at run time.  If I then open this project in 2013 the designer everything looks fine. All controls are within the borders.

NOTE: Im stuck using 2010 as that's what the majority of our projects are designed in. Im also new to WPF.

[image]

Full XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ManageClosedChecks.ClosedCheckList"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None" Title="" Height="461" Width="772" Topmost="True" ShowInTaskbar="False" Name="Window" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Loaded="Window_Loaded" AllowsTransparency="True" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Canvas Height="461" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="746">
    <Grid Height="458" Width="746" Background="Transparent" Canvas.Top="0">
        <Button Content="Reprint" Height="41" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,411,0,0" Name="ReprintBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Click="ReprintBtn_Click" IsEnabled="False" />
        <Button Content="Adjust" Height="41" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,411,0,0" Name="AdjustBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Click="AdjustBtn_Click" IsEnabled="False" />
        <Button Content="CANCEL" Height="41" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,411,91,0" Name="CancelBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Click="CancelBtn_Click" />
        <Button Content="Re-Open" Height="41" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="False" Margin="413,411,0,0" Name="reopenBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Click="reopenBtn_Click" />
        <Button Content="Void" Height="41" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="False" Margin="0,411,354,0" Name="voidBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Click="voidBtn_Click" />
        <Button FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="70" Content="5" Height="186" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="661,45,0,0" Name="UpBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Click="UpBtn_Click" />
        <Button FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="70" Content="6" Height="175" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="661,0,0,50" Name="DownBtn" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="85" Click="DownBtn_Click" />

        <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="363" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="659" FontSize="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,45,0,0">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CheckNum}" >
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="CheckNum" Click="lvUsersColumnHeader_Click">Check</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClosedDateTime, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="ClosedDateTime" Click="lvUsersColumnHeader_Click">Closed Date Time</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CheckID}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="CheckID" Click="lvUsersColumnHeader_Click">Check ID</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Amount}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Amount" Click="lvUsersColumnHeader_Click">Amount</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Employee}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Employee" Click="lvUsersColumnHeader_Click">Employee</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TableNum}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="TableNum" Click="lvUsersColumnHeader_Click">Table</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why do you need a Canvas here? Besides you can send xaml code for your window, what you send for explaining the format is not enough.

Comment: The canvas is there because I want to add more controls later on and I need the freedom to move them in the designer. Ill add the WPF.

Comment: You have some problems with screen dpi and scaling? I can't give exact hints, but I have had similar problems in other tools - I like 120dpi, most (older) software is designed to 96dpi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set SizeToContent property of the window and remove manually given width and height properties of the window.

```
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

Remove  `Height="461" Width="772">`

Then it looks like:

Design Window in VS2010:

[image]

Runtime:

[image]